# How to get current salary rule name as variable in python code field

Tags: odoo-12

Is that possible to get current salary rule name in python code inside salary rule? I know that there are some variable exist, such as "payslip", "rules", "categories" and etc. But I need to use my current  salary rule name in my function inside salary rule? I use Odoo 12